# Overwrite a method from Java Stack class

Tags: java, overriding

I have created my own class "MyStack" that inherits from Stack and stores items "MyItem" that I have declared elsewhere.

```
public class MyStack extends Stack<MyItem> {
    private int pops = 0;

    public MyStack() {
    }
}
```

I want to override the method `pop()` and I do it this way:

```
    @Override
    public MyItem pop() {
        if (this.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        pops++;
        return this.super();
    }
```

This doesn't work because `'java.util.Stack' is not an inner class`.

Then I try using `pop()` instead:

```
    @Override
    public MyItem pop() {
        if (this.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        pops++;
        return this.pop();
    }
```

But as `pop()` is calling `pop()`, what I get is an infinite recursive call and, as a consequence, a `StackoverflowError`.

I don't understand how I should override it.

Comment: `return super.pop();`

Comment: You probably meant to write `return super.pop()`.

Comment: Exactly that. That was me not fully understanding the syntax when overriding a method. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure why you want inherit from Stack but your problem with overriding is quite simple. You should use **super.pop()** [calls parent method] instead of **this.pop()** [calls this method == recursive call]

```
    @Override
public MyItem pop() {
    if (this.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    pops++;
    return super.pop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While you can fix your `pop` method, I have an even better solution for you - stop using `java.util.Stack` completely. It's an ancient relic that has been poorly designed because it *extends* `java.util.Vector` instead of *encapsulating* it. That means I can create a `Stack` instance, fill it, and start removing items from the middle - because it inherits methods like `removeElementAt` from `Vector`.

The better solution is mentioned on https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Stack.html: use a `Deque`. `push`, `pop` and `peek` become `addFirst`, `removeFirst` and `getFirst` according to the documentation, but I prefer `addLast`, `removeLast` and `getLast`.

Like `Stack.pop`, `Deque.removeFirst` and `Deque.removeLast` throw an exception if empty. However, `Deque` also comes with `pollFirst` and `pollLast` which return `null` instead. That's exactly what you're trying to achieve here.

So summarizing: use `Deque` (and implementation `ArrayDeque`) with `addLast`, `pollLast` and `getLast`.